# Write() function of the Turtle graphics library doesn't work with Transcrypt

Tags: javascript, python, turtle-graphics, transcrypt

When I use the `write()` function of the Turtle graphics library in a Python script and then translate it in javascript with Transcrypt, it displays nothing.

My code looks like this:

```
import turtle

def SomeText():
    pen.goto(0, 250)
    pen.pensize(10)
    pen.write("Nothing happens")

pen = turtle.Turtle()
SomeText()
pen.done()
```

The program runs alright in a Python environment but it displays only the turtle line and no text when translated into Javascript through Transcrypt and then is executed on a web browser.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just that Transcrypt doesn't support the `write()` function? If this is the case, how can I combine the turtle graphics with text in a compact way into Javascript? It's not that convenient to use extra html code for text messages.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  What OS?  Are there any compilation errors or warnings when Transcrypt runs?  Are you getting any errors in the web browser console when it runs?

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10. No errors when running. The turtle line from the goto function is displayed correctly. Can you display text with Transcrypt? The web console messages when the above program runs are these:        ::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 07:56:43] "GET /__target__/stackoverflow_example.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 07:56:43] "GET /__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 07:56:43] "GET /__target__/turtle.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -

Comment: It could be that Transcrypt doesn't fully support Python 3.8.  Try running it it with Python 3.7 and see if the problem persists.  There is work currently being done on the library to bring it up to being compatible with Python 3.9, but it is not available yet.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to downgrade just to make transcrypt work. The new messages I receive from web console are these:     ::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 08:14:47] "GET /__target__/stackoverflow_example.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 08:14:48] "GET /__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 08:14:48] "GET /__target__/turtle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 08:14:48] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [16/Nov/2020 08:14:48] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't work for me.  The line `pen.done()` isn't valid as `done()` isn't a method of turtle.  It's an alias of the screen method `mainloop()` and is also available as a top level function that acts on the screen singleton instance.

I'm not saying it'll necessarily fix your stated problem, but to make your original code vaild, change `pen.done()` to `turtle.done()`.  I.e. change it from a non-existent turtle method call to a top level function call.  Then try Transcrypt again...

After that, I'd consider the issue of fonts and do both Python and JavaScript have access to the default `write()` font Arial?

Answer (score -1):

hm.... I don't know if I'm right, as I have left turtle quite a while ago, but aren't you supposed to add a lot more after just `pen.write("nothing happens")`? For example: `pen.write("something happens", True, 'center', font = ([whatever font], [whatever size], 'bold' [or not]))` That may be the problem, but like I said before, I'm not too familiar with turtle and I've also never used Transcript or JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Modify the Turtle graphics program to incorporate the functions of the left and middle mouse buttons. In other words, when you press the left mouse button, a random color changes and the size of the turtle changes, and a line is drawn.